# Is it possible for me to build a raised platform that I can put a carpet on?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Again.. Is it possible for me to build a raised platform that I can put a carpet on? I want to make a raised grass area

Answer (score 0):

Pixel Dust Blocks might work but I believe carpets have to stay on the ground.